# Как оставлять активным пункт меню сайта при открытом модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, html, css, навигация

Имеется меню, которое всегда видимое на мобильной версии сайта.

При нажатии на пункт меню открывается модальное окно. При этом меню остаётся видимым.

Сейчас используются псевдоклассы :focus на активных пунктах. Естественно, при нажатии на область за пределами пункта :focus слетает.

Как сделать так, чтобы пока *привязанное по ID к пункту меню* модальное окно открыто, пункт оставался с :focus, а также чтобы :focus снимался с пункта при закрытии модального окна?

Полагаю, такое возможно только при помощи JS и невозможно только при помощи CSS?

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav-foot">
    <div tabindex="1" id="nf-messages" class="nf" title="Сообщение">
        ○○○○○<br />
        Главная
    </div>
    <div tabindex="2" id="nf-menu" class="nf" title="Меню">
        ○○○○○<br />
        Меню
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav-foot {position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:997;display:table;width:100%;height:56px;font-size:12px;background:#fff;padding:0;margin:0;box-shadow:0 -2px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
#nav-foot .nf {display:table-cell;width:20%;color:#8d8d8d;text-align:center;border:0;padding:2px;margin:0;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;}
#nav-foot .nf:focus {color:#aaa;background:#eee;}
```

Comment: Модальное окно позволяет сделать клик вне его или оно на весь размер экрана?

Comment: Позволяет сделать клик вне его. В т.ч. оно закрывается при нажатии на подложку (overlay). Готов задонатить за помощь со скриптом :)

Comment: Я бы привязал подсветку джаваскриптом, а не фокусом. Открыта модалка - горит, закрыта - не горит. К сожалению, времени написать скрипт нету, даже за донат. Я бы и без доната написал.

Comment: Очень печально. Я расписал полное ТЗ на форумах. Нужно достаточно срочно. Может всё же потратим один вечерок?)

Comment: Вопрос решил хороший человек с помощью JS!